# Localhost web pages take for ever to load with Vagrant... even if all other networking is fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, localhost, vagrant

When I go to `localhost:4567` in my browser, even after the rails server did it's thing, my chrom status is "waiting for..." .

It takes upwards of 30 seconds to reload a single page. All other web browsing works fine, and the Rails server is working fine. It's just the browser page load that takes *for ever*.

I even tried disabling `forwarded_posrt` and browsing right inside the vm... no luck: all requests to localhost take for ever.

Here is my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"


  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 4567

   config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "8"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "10"]
  end

end
```

My host computer is running Ubuntu 13.04. Using virtualbox.

Comment: What is your VirtualBox and Vagrant version? Try to use latest 4.2.16 + 1.2.7. Also, try to comment out the `--cpus` and `--vram` lines, unless you know what you are doing. Does the CPU of your host machine have 8 cores?

Comment: vagrant 1.2.2 and vb 4.2.10. It's first week on the job so I don't have a lot of time to fine tune and waiting a minute between refresh is really making it difficult. My host has 8 core. But I added that after performance trouble. My original config was vanilla.

Comment: what happens if you `curl -i -v localhost:3000` within the guest?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend using a different base box if you really need to customize the VM. Last time I tried using that box the VirtualBox customizations (`vb.customize` on your Vagrantfile) were not being applied correctly. You can double check that by installing the `htop` package and look into how many CPUs and memory it displays.

Another thing you might try is enabling NFS shared folders for your project root, check out this [link](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/nfs.html) for some numbers and in case you are willing to try it out, just add `config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', id: "vagrant-root", nfs: true` to your Vagrantfile

Hope it helps :)